# Relevant item not removing Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tried to remove an item from the array but it's removing the last index of that array, not the relevant one, below is my code. Ex: if I remove the first item from the list then it's removing the last item from the list.

**component.ts code**

```
 this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(id));
```

**html code**

```
<span class="close" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="removeItems(item.Id)">
   <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-2x" style="color: red;"></i>
</span>
```

[List items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP0oZ.png)

I'm using *ngFor loop to get my items. I didn't put that code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If items is a collection of objects then using indexOf with just the id is likely to return -1 every time, which would explain why the last item is being removed.

You would probably need something like

```
const itemToRemove = this.items.findIndex(i => i.id === id);
if(itemToRemove >= 0) {
  this.items.splice(itemToRemove, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you pass negative value to `splice` the function will remove element(s) from the end.
2. You need to pass number of items to be removed. So you are looking for this : `this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(id), 1);`

Comment: Nice catch. I was staring at this for a while until I realized no item count was being passed in as an argument.